# Win7 backup fails with "The system cannot find the file specified" 0x80070002 - has worked before

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a 500 GB USB-disk which has been used as a backup device for a few years now, but now fails without telling me why.

[image]

This is a Dell box with Intel USB-controllers (so the NVIDEA problem does not apply here).  I have previously had problems with a Git package marking a non-existent directory for backup (adding it make the backup succeede).  The inaccessible boot partition problem described in [Windows Backup fails with 0x80070002: "The system cannot find the file specified"](https://superuser.com/q/411474/7401) does not apply to me.

I would appreciate hints on where to look to identify *why* my backup fails so I can fix it.

Comment: Have you made any system changes recently or altered any back up paths?

Comment: I have installed and uninstalled a few programs and done regular Windows updates (nothing pending).  I have local administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this message coincided with this command output

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
No items found that satisfy the query.
```

and the backup completed after this command

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=c: /on=c: /maxsize=1%
Successfully resized the shadow copy storage association
```

so that the output is changed to

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
Shadow Copy Storage association
   For volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{GUID}\
   Shadow Copy Storage volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{GUID}\
   Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 B (0%)
   Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 B (0%)
   Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 1.117 GB (1%)
```